# Removing part of string after specific character (from right to left)

Tags: sql-server

I want this to happen:
(left side is the full string. on the right side, after the "---->" is the output I want to get)

```
3.4.2.12 -----> 3.4.2
3.4.2.1-------? 3.4.2
```

I'm getting this:

```
3.4.2.12-----> 3.4.2.  (note the '.' in the end)
3.4.2.1-----? 3.4.2 (this is good for me)
```

I used this:

```
select 
LEFT( column_name, len( column_name) - charindex('.',   column_name)) 
from table_name
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you have a problem X and think Y is the solution, so you ask for Y when something goes wrong, not X. Are you trying to find the parent in a hierarchy? You should probably use [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-2017) and `GetAncestor(1)`  in that case

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can also be simple string parsing problem, like parsing version number strings or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem right, you want this:

```
select left( column_name, len(column_name) - charindex('.', reverse(column_name)) ) from table_name
```

Proof with hard-coded values:

```
select left( '3.4.2.12', len('3.4.2.12') - charindex('.', reverse('3.4.2.12'))) -- 3.4.2
select left( '3.4.2.1', len('3.4.2.1') - charindex('.', reverse('3.4.2.1'))) -- 3.4.2
```

Comment: Plus one, beat me to it.

Comment: @ShawnBitton Good! Now you can accept my answer (mark it green with tick next to answer text)

Answer (score 1):

If you want everything left of the last '.', you could use this code:

```
USE TEMPDB

SELECT SUBSTRING ('3.4.2.12', 1, LEN ('3.4.2.12') - (CHARINDEX ('.', REVERSE ('3.4.2.12'))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
    @var VARCHAR(20) = '3.4.2.12'

SELECT
    LEFT(@var, LEN(@var) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@var)))

SET @var = '3.4.2.1'

SELECT
    LEFT(@var, LEN(@var) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@var)))
```

We turn the word over, look for the dot, then subtract the position of the last dot from the length.